# Is there a mirror for the daily Natty ISO (/daily-live/current) in Asia?

Tags: 11.04, iso, mirrors, zsync

I've been trying to download Natty for days now, but either the internet here in Vietnam is totally shot or the Ubuntu CD server has a lot of traffic, because I can't get it to download faster than about 15Kbps. Does anyone know of a mirror, preferably close to Vietnam, where I could download (zsync) this image faster? Googling hasn't helped me, nor has Ubuntu's list of mirrors (I get stuck in a rabbithole of FTP folders, and nothing seems to point to the daily image).

Comment: Hmm.  And if anyone has an ISP/Carrier map of the region, that might even help.   Knowing where the major circuits to Vietnam are routed could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that most mirrors only mirror releases or the package archives, but not the daily ISOs.

I've [put together a Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl%3adaily-live/current+-cdimage.ubuntu.com+-inurl%3akubuntu+-inurl%3axubuntu+-inurl%3amythbuntu) that brings up some mirrors that you could try. I haven't seen any that are in Asia though. Below are the first few results I get.

```
http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/download.sourceforge.net/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
http://ftp.df.lkams.kernel.org/pub/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
http://147.32.127.222/MIRRORS/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/MIRRORS/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
http://mirror.leaseweb.com/ubuntu-cdimage/daily-live/current/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try the official link that should find the nearest mirror.
http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download

But as another user has already posted most mirrors do not mirror the daily ISOs.